# Checking custom permissions in Android 6.0 (sdk 23)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I have a few questions regarding how 'custom' permissions work in Android 6.0 with the new runtime permissions. For instance, a declared custom permission like this.

```
<permission android:description="com.mycompany.myapp.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"
        android:label="string resource"
        android:name="string"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

I could not find any information online that specify how to handle this type of custom permissions at runtime in Android M.

Should I handle and check *"com.mycompany.myapp.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"* permission in methods at runtime the same way I check dangerous android perimissions(camera, calendar etc.) with checkSelfPermission()? and provide rationale per Google's new standards?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I guess it's unfortunately not possible. However, it should be possible to send the requesting app a token if the user clicked ok in your custom authorization dialog, and require the app to send you the token to launch your deadly activity, activity-alias or service

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can check the permission with the `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` method using the permission name you declared in the manifest.
So if you declared this in the manifest:

```
<permission android:description="com.mycompany.myapp.DEADLY_ACTIVITY"
    android:label="string resource"
    android:name="com.mycompany.myapp.permissionName"
    android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
```

then you can check the permission anywhere in the app with this:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, "com.mycompany.myapp.permissionName") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```